# Неполные предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, однородные-члены, придаточное-предложение

**"Как выбрать образование и стать настоящим экспертом в своей сфере? Чтобы на совещании твой руководитель и коллеги прислушивались к каждому твоему слову. Чтобы твой работодатель делал всё, чтобы ты на работе чувствовал себя комфортно. Чтобы тебе постоянно поступали приглашения на мероприятия и вакансии от крупных компаний".**

**"Моя задача — дать им все необходимые знания и готовые инструменты, чтобы реализовать эту цель. Провести их по этому лабиринту, показать, какие двери надо открыть и где нужно пригнуться".**

Выше представлены отрывки из текстов моего блога в одной социальной сети. По идее в первом и втором примерах предложения, следующие за первым, должны входить в первое предложение в качестве придаточного предложений (в первом примере) и в качестве однородных членов (во втором примере), но были вынесены мной в отдельное предложение с целью избежать нагромождения и улучшить читабельность.

Правомерно ли в публицистике и в интернет-блогах использовать подобные неполные предложения? Или это является чересчур вольным и синтаксически неприемлемым построением предложений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, это вполне легитимный грамматико-стилистический прием, используемый как в публицистике, так и в художественной литературе.

Он называется **присоединением**. Как будто вы выражаете дополнительные мысли, возникающие в сознании после того, как основная мысль уже высказана.

Впрочем, можно также считать, что применен прием **парцелляции** — намеренное расчленение текста на несколько пунктуационно самостоятельных отрезков, с тем, чтобы сделать текст более эмоционально насыщенным, выделить отдельные части.

По ходу дела хочу обратить Ваше внимание на некоторые выражения, которые показались мне  неудачными.

> Чтобы твой работодатель делал всё, чтобы ты на работе чувствовал себя комфортно

Два *чтобы*, стоящие на разных "уровнях вложенности" предложений. При чтении вслух может быть воспринято неверно. Минимальная правка: замнить *чтобы* на *для того, чтобы*. "Чтобы твой работодатель делал всё для того, чтобы ты на работе чувствовал себя комфортно"

> Чтобы тебе постоянно поступали приглашения на мероприятия и вакансии от крупных компаний

Во-первых, я бы предпочел стандартное выражение "приглашение на работу" модерному "на вакансию". (К чему указывать, что приглашают именно на вакантную должность? Ведь это и так ясно.). Во вторых, мне не совсем ясно, о каких мероприятиях идет речь и почему они стоят в одном ряду с таким важным событием, как приглашение на работу.

> реализовать эту цель

Сочетание неверное. Цели достигают , а планы реализуют.

Comment: *Чтобы твой работодатель делал всё для того, чтобы ты на работе чувствовал себя комфортно,* - не выход. М. б., *...делал всё для создания у тебя чувства комфорта на работе.*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova, критику принимаю, но и Ваша правка в канцелярском стиле мне не очень нравится. – М_Г 1 час назад